# Do you switch between things in plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

I was just now watching a TV programme where a character said "I'm concerned when we switch brands of coffee".

Ignoring the choice of:

> switch brands of coffee  // switch coffee brands

Is it correct to say *brands* (pl.), because to me both the above and:

> switch brand of coffee // switch coffee brand

sound fine, or at least, I do hear both. Which is "more correct"?

I can justify either: the sentence speaks of switching to a singular thing, but then it switches between plural things.

Comment: Try a Google search for "switch brand" -"the switch brand" and see how many of the first 20 say results are relevant. How does this compare with the results for "switch brands"?

Comment: Did I miss the memo on widespread use equating to correctness?

Comment: @OllieFord: What do you think "correctness" means? (A language is a social construct, shared by its speakers. If a usage is widespread among them, what on Earth would it mean for it not to be "correct"?)

Comment: @ruakh It would mean a lot of people were incorrect. People take this "social construct" thing too far.

Comment: @OllieFord: I'm guessing that you did understand my comment, but didn't have an answer, so decided to cleverly misinterpret it. Do I have that right?

Comment: Just because a lot of people say the same thing, doesn't mean there right.

Comment: @OllieFord: Obviously. If someone says X, and the reality is Y, then that someone is wrong. But I'm not sure how that applies here. When it comes to correct usage, what is the *reality* in question, if it's not the real usage of real speakers?

Comment: @Ollie, yes, it seems that you did. Language is a living, evolving thing. Any ‘correctness’ in it is defined exactly by majority usage. Not by anything else. Not dictionaries, grammar books, linguists, or encyclopaedias. Those all _describe_ language: they don't tell you what is or is not _correct_, only what is or is not in common use.

Comment: @Janus Are all the prescriptivists been executed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Whether you *switch brands* or *change trains*, the idiom is pretty clear:

[image]

[image]

If the object changed is indeterminate, the plural is overwhelmingly preferred to the singular, by a factor of 25-40 to 1—doubtless because you are exchanging one brand/train for another.

In the rare case of a determinate object, however—if you change *your* train or they switch *their* brand—the plural vanishes and the singular rules.

Comment: Good additional point.

Answer (score 0):

When you switch something, you need at least two things: A (from which you switch) and B (to which you switch). Therefore "something" should be plural.
See an example in Cambridge Dictionary; 
After the bank robbery, the gang switched cars (= left one car and got into another).
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/switch

Comment: What does your answer (“switch cars”) contribute that [StoneyB’s answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/153649/26083#153674) (“change trains”) doesn’t already say?